# Result type from cursor.fetchall() is list of tuples, but doc shows tuple of tuples

Tags: django, django-3.0

```
from django.db import connection

conn = connection.cursor()
conn.execute("some select query..")
print( conn.fetchall() )
```

This shows that result from `cursor.fetchall()` is list of tuples, though in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/) there is example:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id FROM test LIMIT 2");
>>> cursor.fetchall()
((54360982, None), (54360880, None))
```

That shows that result is not list, but tuple of tuples.

Little bit confused, What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Considering the amounts of database backends supported by Django (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite3), and their various cursors of their own a difference of a list and a tuple can very easily happen right?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - You mean that for mySQL it's tuple but for another database it may be list ?

Comment: Might be, didn't test it but Django mostly just wraps the cursors for the databases a little bit and the `fetchall` method is used of the cursor itself so there are high chances of such minor differences being present.

Answer (score 0):

`(54360982, None)` is a tuple. And `((54360982, None), (54360880, None))` is a tuple of tuples, which is like in the docs. That is why the return type is also the builtin `tuple`, checked with mySQL and sqlalchemy which again uses MySQLdb for the cursor:

```
import sqlalchemy
# from MySQLdb.cursors import Cursor --> this would be the cursor type if we needed it

print(type(cursor.fetchall()))
```

Out:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

Your remark

> This shows that result from cursor.fetchall() is list of tuples

seems to say that `from django.db import connection` leads to an output:

```
<class 'list'>
```

At least if I understand you right. If that is true, I do not understand it either, I can only say from the test with sqlalchemy that this looks like a mere `django` problem, as already said in the comments.